# ASP.NET MVC AjaxActionLink OnComplete and OnSuccess property and Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a dialog box in my ASP.NET application with an AJAX ActionLink.

The Ajax ActionLink inserts a partial view into a div in the current view.

I've called a function OnComplete (and I've tried OnSuccess, too) that calls the dialog function for JQuery UI, like so:

```
function() loaddialog {
$("ContainerwithInsertedPartialView").dialog();
}
```

Nevertheless, it display the dialog.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have your function definition wrong, for one.  You need to use the id selector (prepend a hash) for another.

```
function loaddialog() {
    $('#ContainerwithInsertedPartialView').dialog();
}
```